# Dreamweaver alternative with precise visual div placement?

Tags: css, dreamweaver

I am mainly a programmer, and while I have extensive Photoshop and Illustrator experience, alongside a decent understanding of html5, and CSS, I have just never been able to do a proper WYSIWYG drag and drop website design with dreamweaver ( kind of like you can with visual studio.net or eclipse windows builder).

I don't understand why it is so damn hard ? the CSS divs and layers are sooo complicated to place, you have to do all these calculations, sometimes increasing margins,decreasing margins, type of divs , maybe it is just me, but after many months of headaches I have switched to using a website builder such as one provided by webeden.co.uk ( this isn't an advert, i m not affiliated with them, ). I mean ALL i want to do is drag and drop a few divs, click a few buttons and for them to just work, and webeden can do it online and the dreamweaver which is the software solely designed for web development cant. I am desperate to switch back to dreamweaver as it is a lot more powerful, but doing the layouts is a nightmare.

Is it just me, do I just need hundreds of hours to get all my divs and spans just right? or maybe I am not suited as an occasional web-developer? or did adobe put a curse on me for leaving dreamweaver ?

thanks

Comment: "alongside a decent understanding of html5, and CSS..." No, you dont.

Comment: If there was such a thing I would be out of a job

Comment: Sounds like web-development isn't for you. Otherwise visit http://www.codecademy.com/ and learn more about the ins and outs of web-development and design.

Comment: I appreciate Keeg's & Captainrad's  simple answers thanks guys , but Ark there is no need to be sarcastic. You don't have to answer if you are so stuckup. it was a simple question.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately or fortunately for me, to have nicely coded, custom website you need a human being with programing experience and knowledge of latest techniques and technologies. Sure you can create a word document and and save it as an html file, but have you seen the code behind it? Bleh. But you as a designer probably don't care about that, a developer does and so do server people who see your bloated website eats up bandwidth. So the answer is, you are just not suited to be an occasional developer just as developers are not suited as occasional designers no matter how good their Paint skill are

Comment: and this is why our bill > payment

Answer (score -1):

In all honesty dreamweaver is bloatware. It costs too much, and a real professional wouldn't touch it.

That being said. The guy talking about crap code and bandwidth is obviously a derp. The code itself on even a large site will not chew up that much bandwidth. The major bandwidth usage in any site will be it's media.. i.e. images, videos, music etc..

In my honest opinion, one only needs notepad to create a decent website.

As for drag-n-drop technology. I have yet to see an implementation of it that is fast, powerful, and complex enough to have the options for what i want to do. That isn't counting what the resulting code would look like.

My suggestion to anyone creating a website, is for them to learn html, and css. There are more powerful languages out there to build sites with, but for a beginner, html, and css are a great foundation. After that if you wish, go on to learn javascript, php, perl, and python.

Comment: Bandwidth is always a concern, and yes the code itself can be significant. Just ask the guy viewing your site on his phone with a crappy connection. Also, real-life tests have shown an increase in loading time as small as 100ms results in lower sales and traffic.

Comment: Also from the [FAQ](http://stackoverflow.com/faq#etiquette) - `Civility is required at all times; rudeness will not be tolerated.`